# Format for social connections data in Nimble API

Tags: json, crm

I'm doing an integration with Nimble CRM using their API. I'm collecting data from a web form and creating a new contact in Nimble.

The creation of a new contact is working fine.  The ONLY thing I'm having trouble with is adding "social connections" to the profile. The JSON I submit to the API (see below) is valid.  I tested it at jsonlint.com (without the comments of course).  When the contact is created in Nimble, the "social connections" (linkedin, twitter, etc.) simply are not showing in the newly created Nimble profile.

The documentation at https://nimble.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contacts/fields/ *seems* straightforward enough - the value to be submitted for linkedin is the full linkedin URL. I've copy/pasted the appropriate linkedin URL directly from the browser, so I'm confident it's correct.

What I want to know is the correct json structure for submitting "social connections" data to the API.  Frankly, the documentation for this API sucks and I can't glean an answer from the cryptic references. What I've tried looks like this:

```
{
    //this part is working just fine
    "record_type": "person",
    "fields": {
        "first name": [{
            "value": "Fred",
            "modifier": ""
        }],
        "last name": [{
            "value": "Tester",
            "modifier": ""
        }],

        "email": [{
            "value": "fred@testsite.com",
            "modifier": "Work"
        }]

    },
    "tags": "VIP",
    //this is the block that is having no effect
    "social_connections": {
        "linkedin": {
            "value": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/fredtester/",
            "modifier": "",
            "group": "Contact Info",
            "label": "linkedin"
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried it without the "modifier", "group" and "label" attributes of the "linkedin" array.  Nada, nothing.

BTW, the API call in all cases is successful - i.e. no error codes are returned.

Does anyone have any experience successfully integrating social connections with Nimble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally heard back from Nimble API support (8 days later).  It appears that the documentation is not current.  The "social connections" field has been discontinued and the correct way to add a linkedin URL for instance is as follows:

```
"linkedin" : {
    "value": "'.$linkedin.'",
    "modifier": ""
}
```

When creating a new contact, the linkedin block is added as part of the "fields" array like this:

```
"fields: {
    "first name": [{
        "value": "Fred",
        "modifier": ""
    }],
    "last name": [{
        "value": "Tester",
        "modifier": ""
    }],
    "email": [{
        "value": "fred@testsite.com",
        "modifier": "Work"
    }]
    "linkedin" : {
        "value": "'.$linkedin.'",
        "modifier": ""
    }
}
```

Having made the change, the URL for linkedin is correctly created with the contact.

Hope this helps someone else.  If someone finds this with >1500 rep points, please create a Nimble tag.  Unfortunately, I can not.